# Can I shift to 1 machine(higher config) with 2 nodes than 2 machines(lower config) each with 1 node in selenium grid?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, serenity-bdd, selenium-grid2, selenium-java

I am using 2 windows VMs each with 2 CPU cores and 8GB RAM each and my tests run Ok so far using selenium grid. Here I run 7 instances of chrome parallelly distributed over these 2 machines, means 1 machine may have 4 instances of chrome and another can have 3 instances at a time. There is no OOM or infra issue I face frequently.
To be noted, hub and 1 node is in one machine and another node(only) is on another machine.

Somehow these two machines needs to be discontinued and other machine with higher configuration will be shared. Now I am thinking to use 2 nodes and 1 hub in this one machine itself and run my tests in parallel(7 instances) on these 2 nodes.

**My question is what should be the minimum configuration of this new machine that I should ask for to run my tests smoothly?
Also will there be any other impact of using one machine only, like problem of all chrome instances in one machine with 2 nodes even if configuration is high(i.e- 4 CPU cores and 16 GB RAM)?**

Answer (score 0):

Before finalizing the machine configuration, you should consider the following factors:

Size and complexity of your tests: If your tests require significant CPU and memory resources, you might need a higher configuration to ensure optimal performance.
Test data size: If your tests involve large amounts of data, you might need more memory to accommodate the data in memory and avoid swapping to disk.

if you are using Selenium grid 4 , i would suggest once running it in standalone mode on the new machine

```
java -jar selenium-server-4.8.0.jar standalone
```

it will automatically detect the number of processor and set a max concurrency limit for the node, which will give you some idea on what grid assumes to be the maximum number of tests can be run efficiently without overloading any node.

```
07:52:43.685 INFO [NodeOptions.getSessionFactories] - Detected 16 available processors
```

Running all 7 instances of Chrome on one machine with 2 nodes might cause a bottleneck, especially if your tests require significant CPU and memory resources.